# Ranorex test automation issue

Tags: android, automation, ranorex

Whenever I deploy with Ranorex automation testing tool with an Android tablet device, it shows the following error: "There was a problem parsing the package".

Comment: Welcome to SO. Maybe you would want to add some more information, for people to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use "ADB install" in order to deploy the APK?
Take a look [here](https://www.ranorex.com/help/latest/android-testing) to see more about Android testing.